# Spring Boot 2.6.6 fails to run tests, but is able to load application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I'm currently building an Spring boot application that is meant as a middle-man between an SPA and another platform. When started normally, the applications runs, but tests always fails for some reasons.

When just adding a test case to check if the context is loaded (like described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) and the code piece below), the tests automatically fail and cannot be loaded.

```java
    package com.company.it.gdppwaapi;
    
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    
    @SpringBootTest
    class GdpPwaApiApplicationTests {
        @Test
        void contextLoads() {
    
        }
    }
```

The resulting error message that I get is as follows:

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.IdentityHashMap.hash(IdentityHashMap.java:297)
        at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:428)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.add(Collections.java:5515)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:82)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
        ...
```

*The last 2 lines are continually repeated in the logs, so I've shorten it*

When I use IntelliJ's debugger, I also see that the following exception is thrown from the `void contextLoads()` function:
[![IntelliJ's Debugger output][1]][1]

I've tried the following things already:

- Setting the `SpringBootTest` annotation as follows:

```java
  @SpringBootTest(classes = GdpPwaApiApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

- Extending the Application context with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` in the test file
- Adding the logback dependencies explicitly (As some other projects in our company explicitly state that in the `pom.xml`)

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

- Adding the component scan that is in the main startup class to the test class.

Has somebody had a similar solution like this and found a way to resolve it? Thank you!

`pom.xml` Dependencies

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Main startup class

```java
    package com.company.it.gdppwaapi;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan({"com.company.it.security", "com.company.it.gdppwaapi"})
    public class GdpPwaApiApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(GdpPwaApiApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Main test class

```java
    package com.company.it.gdppwaapi;
    
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    
    @SpringBootTest
    class GdpPwaApiApplicationTests {
        @Test
        void contextLoads() {
    
        }
    }
```

---

**Update 1**

After searching for a while, we found out that the security package searches for a logback configuration file. While this has resolved the `StackOverflowException`, this revealed the underlying error that was being returned:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
```

From what I read around the web, it could be Mockito related. Any help on what is could be would be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqh43.png

Comment: Why are you ` @ComponentScan` scanning? The @SpringBootApplication will do it by itself.

Comment: @ZahidKhan It's a requirement for the self-written security dependency my company uses. I've tried it using without component scanning, but this doesn't work. As they don't have proper documentation and every other project they have created it uses it, this is the only way I got it working

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using? When you start to add things like OAuth and JWT with some old versions that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: @M.Deinum Spring Boot 2.6.6