# Java Spring Boot: Unable to create application context & run integration suite

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-aop, spring-test

## The context

I'm currently building an Spring boot application (Version 2.6.6) that is meant as a middle-man between an SPA and another platform. This application doesn't use any database, it communicates between the services by using their respective `REST` api's.

## The problem

### The initial incident

When started normally, the applications runs and operates normally, but when trying to start the application for running tests, the application will always fail for some reason. This test classes doesn't include any tests, but has a `contextLoads()` in order to validate that the context is loaded, as detailed in the [Spring Boot testing guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/#:%7E:text=Test%20the%20Application). Here's my test class as reference:

```java
package com.company.it.gdppwaapi;

import com.company.it.gdppwaapi.controllers.DashboardReporter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GdpPwaApiApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private DashboardReporter reporter;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(reporter).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

This has turned into a wild goose chase, trying to find the actual bug that causes this, because whenever the integration suite is runned, we get this exception thrown our way:

```java
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:78)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
```

(*The `at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)` is repeated continuously*)

I've narrowed it down that one of our Maven dependencies is causing the issue, written for handling authorization and authentication. This version is written in a older version of Spring boot (to be specific: `2.1.6.RELEASE`). This dependency makes use of Aspects in order to achieve this. This is the main Startup class as reference:

```java
package com.company.it.gdppwaapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.company.it.security", "com.company.it.gdppwaapi"})
public class GdpPwaApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GdpPwaApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*(`scanBasePackages` is needed in order to pick up the component of the Maven dependency)*

### Steps taken to discover more error information

#### Turning Logback off

Because of the `StackOverflow` we get, I decided to turn logback off to see what this does by introducing a XML file:

```xml
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds" debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level %logger{20} %mdc{username} - %msg%n%ex{full}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="OFF">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This gave me some more information about what is happening:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object
```

Because of this and the fact that the Maven dependency in question has a `@Transactional` annotation on a certain class, I thought it might have been related to [this post, called "Spring Bean Injection Failing Due To Proxy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648397/spring-bean-injection-failing-due-to-proxy). Unfortunately, after applying the suggested solution, this didn't solve my issue.

### Setting the Logback to Debug

Because the previous log didn't gave us a lot of info, I decided to maybe try the opposite and set the log level to `debug` in order to see if this gave me some more clarity:

```xml
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds" debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level %logger{20} %mdc{username} - %msg%n%ex{full}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This gave us a lot more info about what Spring Boot does when starting up, but I noticed that there's an error thrown my way while Spring Boot tries to build the Application Context:

```
DEBUG o.s.v.b.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean  - Failed to set up a Bean Validation provider
javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:259)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidatorAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(ValidatorAdapter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

This was quite interesting, as my project doesn't use `Hibernate` as a dependency, **but the problematic dependency does**. As the error message says, I try installing the Hibernate validator in 2 different methods:

1. By adding the `hibernate-validator` dependency to my `pom.xml` and rerunning the application, as detailed in the [Hibernate documentation](https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)
2. By explicitly including the `spring-boot-starter-validator`in my `pom.xml` and rerun the application, as [here it's detailed that it needs to be included after Spring Boot 2.3](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)

But with both of these, the same issue is thrown.

## What I already tried:

### Based on `ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)` issue

- Setting the SpringBootTest annotation as follows:

  ```java
      @SpringBootTest(classes = GdpPwaApiApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
  ```
- Extending the Application context with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` in the test file
- Extending the Application context with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` in the test file
- Adding the component scan that is in the main startup class to the test class.
- Changing the `spring-aspects` dependency to `spring-boot-starter-aop` instead.
- Annotating the main application class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

### Based on the `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to unwrap proxied object`

- [Unwraping the proxy object, as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648397/spring-bean-injection-failing-due-to-proxy).

### Based on the `javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException` exception

- Add the `hibernate-validator` dependency to my `pom.xml` and rerunning the application, as detailed in the [Hibernate documentation](https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)
- Explicitly include the `spring-boot-starter-validator`in my `pom.xml` and rerun the application, as [here it's detailed that it needs to be included after Spring Boot 2.3](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)

## My questions

I have now several questions:

- Relating to the `javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException`, what is the correct way to install and configure the `hibernate-provider` so that this exception doesn't get thrown anymore?
- Has somebody has a similar issue like this and found a solution for this?

## Code references I can share

### Main Startup class

```java
package com.company.it.gdppwaapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.company.it.security", "com.company.it.gdppwaapi"})
public class GdpPwaApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GdpPwaApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

### Main Test class

```java
package com.company.it.gdppwaapi;

import com.company.it.gdppwaapi.controllers.DashboardReporter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GdpPwaApiApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private DashboardReporter reporter;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(reporter).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

### Current `pom.xml`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Company utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.it</groupId>
            <artifactId>copmany-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.company.it.copilot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>babel-base-jpa2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: The `hibernate-validator` isn't the issue, if you see it is a DEBUG message and thrown by the conditional rule to check if `hibernate-validator` is on the classpath and to determine if it needs to be enabled or not. What still is suspicious is the old spring security dependencies those shouldn't be needed with the newer Spring Security OAuth support. Springdoc 1.6.4 is for Spring Boot 2.6.2, in theory compatible but you want to try 1.6.7 which matches your Spring Boot version. Finally the `MockitoExtension` doesn't make sense in your test, remove it.

Comment: Additionally you already asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700992/spring-boot-2-6-6-fails-to-run-tests-but-is-able-to-load-application) why didn't you edit/update that one.

Comment: @M.Deinum I made a new one, as the question didn't resolve anymore around the Proxy Object, but Hibernate. If I need to delete this question and update the other, let me know, so that I can take care of that.